# Eventos Drag-Drop geram contadores internos?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma `div` cada vez que solto uma imagem em cima de outra `div`, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte:

- Na 1 vez: cria 1 Div;
- Na 2 vez: cria 2 Div;
- Na 3 vez: cria 3 Div;

Existe algum contador interno nos eventos `ondragstart` e `ondrop`?

```
<img ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="icon" src="imagens/01.jpg" />
```

---

```
function dragStart(event) {
  elem = event.target.getAttribute('id');
}
function drop(event) {
  $('<div class="img"></div>').appendTo('#centro'); 
  $('#'+elem).appendTo('.midia');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem o restante do código não posso ter certeza mas, talvez, este seja um caso de propagação do evento drop para todas as `div` existentes na página.

Minha sugestão para você é adicionar um `stopPropagation` na função `drop`.

```
function drop(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('<div class="img"></div>').appendTo('#centro'); 
  $('#'+elem).appendTo('.midia');
}
```

Se isto solucionar o seu problema, a questão é apenas o mecanismo de propagação de eventos funcionando. Se isto for desconhecido para você, sugiro uma pesquisa sobre o tema mas em curtas palavras:

> Eventos gerados em nós filhos são propagados para nós pai. Se algum dos nós em níveis acima na árvore de nós (DOM) também possuir o listener *ondrop* definido com a função `drop` (ou qualquer outra), este listener será executado.

Comment: Isso não funcionou. Eu inseri depois alert(event.isPropagationStopped()); para testar se é mesmo pela propagação de eventos e resultou true com a continuação do problema.

Comment: O problema é o nome da classe, mídia. Toda vez que eu envio uma imgem, ele cria uma no Div, mas também envia na Div anterior que possui o mesmo nome. Vou tentar criar uma Div sem classe ou alterar o nomes da classe toda vez que uma noma imagem é criada.